# Custom Folder encryption in ios swift3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am saving my images and videos in custom folder by using the Native iOS App. But I need to encrypt that folder as either hiding Folder or setting password for folder opening.I want to know what is best method either hiding folder or setting password for that folder.How to do this task in iOS swift.Could anyone guide me for the best solution

Comment: Hiding it from what?  Encrypting it from access by who?

Comment: Just use the encryption that iPhone provides, that should be enough.

Comment: @ Cristik: could you please send any related links

Comment: Are you talking about in an app you are developing or using the iOS Photos app in general?

Comment: I am taking about in an app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS, you can never open any folder physically. So what's the purpose of setting password for the folder? 
Even if you want to enable data protect, visit developer.apple.com, against the bundle identifier, enable "Data Protection" or else you can do the same in "Capabilities" section of your project in Xcode. 
Folders & files created by your application can only access your them, so no need to put any password or encrypt them. 
Even if you want to have encryption, you need to write your own algorithm to encrypt the files before saving and decrypt them while accessing/reading. But setting password for folder won't be helpful.